# constexpr vs macro vs función inline

Tags: c++, c++11

Desde tiempos inmemoriales tenemos a nuestra disposición las macros y las funciones inline:

```
#define SUMA(a,b) a+b

inline int suma(int a, int b)
{ return a + b; }
```

Sin embargo desde C++11 está disponible `constexpr` (cuya funcionalidad se ha incrementado notablemente en C++14):

```
constexpr int suma(int a, int b)
{ return a + b; }
```

¿Qué diferencia hay entre estas tres opciones? ¿Qué opción sería más recomendable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MACROS**

Las macros son una herencia directa de C. Una de las principales fallas de las macros es que no poseen tipado, es decir, le puedes pasar cualquier tipo de dato a la macro que si el código resultante es compilable no vas a obtener errores:

```
#define SUMA(a,b) a+b

std::string c1 = "abc";
std::cout << SUMA(4,5) << std::endl; // 9
std::cout << SUMA(2,3.5) << std::endl; // 5.5
std::cout << SUMA(c1,"def") << std::endl; // abcdef
std::cout << SUMA("abc","def") << std::endl; // ERROR, no sabe cómo sumar dos const char*
```

Otro problema que tiene la macro es que va a explotar los parámetros de forma literal, lo cual puede arrojar resultados extraños:

```
#define MACRO(a,b) (2*a+2*b)/(a+b)

int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 1;

std::cout << MACRO(num1++,num2) << std::endl
          << num1 << std::endl
          << num2 << std::endl;
```

Alguien podría pensar que la salida de este código va a ser:

```
2 -> (4*2+2*1)/(4+1) = (8+2)/4 = 10/5 = 2
5 -> num1++ = 4+1 = 5
1 -> num2 = 1
```

Sin embargo la salida real es (en mi caso):

```
1 -> ???
6 -> ((2*num++)+2*b)/((num++)+b) -> hay dos incrementos
1 -> num2 = 1
```

El primer resultado no lo he calculado manualmente porque el resultado final dependerá del compilador (y el problema lo tiene el postincremento):

- El compilador procesa los postincrementos una vez calculado el resultado:

  ```
  (2*4+2*1)/(4+1) -> 2
  ```
- El compilador procesa `(2*4)` y calcula un postincremento:

  ```
  (2*4+2*1)/(5+1) -> 1
  ```
- El compilador procesa la ecuación al revés y calcula un postincremento después de `(4+1)`:

  ```
  (2*5+2*1)/(4+1) -> 2
  ```

Es facil adivinar que esto el ejemplo se puede complicar todo lo que queramos:

```
#define MACRO(a,b) a*a*b

std::cout << MACRO(4+5,2) << std::endl;
```

¿Cual es el resultado? La respuesta correcta es:

```
4+5*4+5*2 = 4+20+10 = 34
```

Por todos estos problemas las macros deberían ser evitadas en la inmensa mayoría de las situaciones (y otros que no se enumeran).

**FUNCIONES INLINE**

Para evitar todos estos problemas derivados de las macros surgieron las funciones `inline`. Una función inline posee un tipado fuerte y garantiza la estabilidad de los parámetros (los preincrementos, postincrementos, etc) se calculan una vez). El código anterior utilizando una función inline:

```
inline int func(int a, int b)
{ return a*a*b; }

std::cout << func(4+5,2) << std::endl;
```

El resultado ahora sería:

```
a = 9, b = 2
a*a*b = 9*9*2 = 162
```

Y si convertimos el ejemplo de los postincrementos:

```
inline int func(int a, int b)
{ return (2*a+2*b)/(a+b); }

int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 1;

std::cout << func(num1++,num2) << std::endl
          << num1 << std::endl
          << num2 << std::endl;
```

El resultado sería **SIEMPRE**:

```
2 -> (2*4+2*1)/(4+1) = 10/5 = 2
5 -> a++ = 4+1
1 -> b = 1
```

**FUNCIONES CONSTEXPR**

Las funciones *constexpr* aparecieron en el estándar C++11. Son similares a las funciones inline con el añadido de que el resultado de la operación "*puede*" ser precalculado en tiempo de compilación. En sí mismo esto puede no parecer una ventaja evidente, puesto que las funciones inline, actualmente, también pueden ser optimizadas en el mismo sentido, como se aprecia en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
inline int factorialInline(int n)
{
    return n <= 1? 1 : (n * factorialInline(n - 1));
}

constexpr int factorialConstExpr(int n)
{
    return n <= 1? 1 : (n * factorialConstExpr(n - 1));
}

extern void funcExtern(int);

int main()
{
  funcExtern(factorialInline(10));
  funcExtern(factorialConstExpr(10));
}
```

Cuya salida en ensamblador (clang 3.9.1 -std=c++11 -O3) es la siguiente:

```
push    rax
mov     edi, 3628800
call    funcExtern(int)
mov     edi, 3628800
call    funcExtern(int)
xor     eax, eax
pop     rcx
ret
```

Ahí se aprecia como el resultado de ambas funciones (`10! = 3628800`)  ha sido precalculado en tiempo de compilación.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entonces entre usar `inline` o `constexpr`?

La diferencia es que `constexpr`, debido a las restriccines que implementa (no pretendo enumerarlas porque esta entrada no es un curso de `constexpr`), permite asegurar mejores optimizaciones en el código. Veamos otro ejemplo:

```
inline int factorialInline(int n)
{
    return n <= 1? 1 : (n * factorialInline(n - 1));
}

constexpr int factorialConstExpr(int n)
{
    return n <= 1? 1 : (n * factorialConstExpr(n - 1));
}

extern void funcExtern(int);

const int valor1 = factorialInline(10);
const int valor2 = factorialConstExpr(10);

int main()
{
  funcExtern(valor1);
  funcExtern(valor2);
}
```

Código ensamblador:

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rax
    mov     edi, dword ptr [rip + valor1]
    call    funcExtern(int)
    mov     edi, 3628800
    call    funcExtern(int)
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rcx
    ret

_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp:             # @_GLOBAL__sub_I_example.cpp
    mov     dword ptr [rip + valor1], 3628800
    ret
```

Aquí se puede apreciar como la función `inline` implica dos operaciones de copia (una para almacenar el resultado en `valor1` y otra para llamar a `funcExtern`), mientras que en el caso de la versión `constexpr` el compilador se permite el lujo de utilizar directamente el valor allí donde se requiere.

En posteriores estándares las capacidades de `constexpr` se han incrementado por lo que cada vez se refuerza como la alternativa más potente.

**CONCLUSIÓN**

Lo recomendable, según mi experiencia, es priorizar las funciones `constexpr`. Cuando no se pueda utilizar esta vía, por la razón que sea, la segunda opción deberían ser las funciones `inline`, reservando las macros para aquellas situaciones en las que las dos opciones anteriores no estén disponibles.