# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre macros y plantilla C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++1z, c++17

1. En tiempo de compilación, ¿hay diferencias con respecto al rendimiento de la compilación?
2. Cuando se ejecuta el programa, ¿cuáles son las diferencias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia entre macros y plantillas es que las primeras son una herramienta del pre-procesador y las segundas una herramienta del lenguaje.

#### Fases de la traducción.

En C++ el código pasa por [nueve fases [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) para generar un archivo ejecutable:

1. Se ajustan los caracteres del código para que coincidan con los caracteres que acepta el estándar.
2. Las instrucciones multilínea se juntan en una sola línea.
3. Se eliminan los comentarios.
4. **Se ejecuta el preprocesador**.
5. Los caracteres de los literales de carácter o cadena se pasan a la codificación del sistema.
6. Se concatenan los literales de cadena adyacentes.
7. **Se compila**.
8. **Se examinan las instancias de plantillas que han sido instanciadas**.
9. Se enlazan todos los componentes en el archivo ejecutable.

Las macros se "*ejecutan*" en la fase 4, las plantillas en la fase 7. Una macro funciona igual que un buscar-reemplazar de un procesador de texto, supongamos que tenemos este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#define UNO 11
#define DOS UNO + UNO
#define TRES 333
#define PATATA(A, B) A - B

int main()
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "Debug";
#else
    std::cout << "Release";
#endif

    std::cout << PATATA(UNO, DOS) + PATATA(DOS, TRES);
    return 0;
}
```

En la fase 4 se ejecuta el preprocesador que:

- Reemplazará `#include <iostream>` por el archivo `iostream` completo.
- Todo lo que esté en condicionales (`#ifdef`, `#else`, `#endif`) será eliminado o se mantendrá según la condición.
- Se buscarán los símbolos de las "macros" y se substituirán (como un buscar-reemplazar) por el valor que representan, así que el código anterior quedaría así:

```
Aquí está todo el archivo iostream
...
...
...





int main()
{



    std::cout << "Release";


    std::cout << 11 - 11 + 11 + 11 + 11 - 333;
    return 0;
}
```

Y ese es el código que finalmente en la fase 7 se compila. Sabiendo esto, tus respuestas son:

> En tiempo de compilación, ¿hay diferencias con respecto al rendimiento de la compilación?

Las macros apenas afectan al tiempo de compilación ya que no forman parte de la compilación (fase 7) en si. Tienen un impacto sobre el tiempo de traducción total, pero es pequeño; lo que más afectará en tiempo serán las inclusiones.

Las plantillas tienen un impacto considerable en el tiempo de compilación, en cada [unidad de traducción [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) se instanciarán y re-compilarán aún habiendo sido instanciadas y compiladas en otras unidades de traducción.

> Cuando se ejecuta el programa, ¿Cuáles son las diferencias?

Cuando se ejecuta el programa se ejecuta, evidentemente, lo que se compiló; así que la pregunta no tiene sentido: tanto si se compilaron plantillas como si se compiló un programa que contenía macros la diferencia será, obviamente, el código compilado.

Comment: gracias por responder y aclararme las fases por la que pasa el fichero fuente.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de responder, recomiendo leer esta otra pregunta: [constexpr vs macro vs función inline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/51926/463)

> En tiempo de compilación, ¿hay diferencias con respecto al rendimiento de la compilación?

Dado que las plantillas pueden llamarse de forma recursiva, la compilación de plantillas puede requerir más tiempo de compilación.

> Cuando se ejecuta el programa, ¿cuáles son las diferencias?

Cuando se ejecuta... ninguna. Al programa final no viajan macros ni plantillas sino instrucciones máquina.

La diferencia se encuentra a nivel de código fuente y durante la fase de compilación.

Las macros son algo heredado de C y, debido a ello, son elementos con ciertas carencias.

**1. No poseen tipado**

La macro es tratada por el preprocesador, que es el primer elemento que entra en juego durante la compilación. El preprocesador no atiende a la sintaxis de C++... solo *escucha*, las directivas del preprocesador y nada más. El compilador, que si realiza el chequeo de tipos, entra en juego a continuación, pero ya puede ser tarde.

Supongamos una macro simple y, aparentemente, inocua:

```
#define MIN(a,b) a < b ? a : b
```

Nada del otro mundo, nos devuelve el mayor elemento de dos que le pasamos como parámetro:

```
std::cout << MIN(5,8); // Imprime 5
```

Ahora bien, como no tiene tipado, nada nos impide hacer lo siguiente:

```
std::cout << MIN("abc","def");
```

¿Qué imprimirá ahora? Esta vez la macro se sustituirá por:

```
std::cout << "abc" < "def" ? "abc" : "def";
```

Y a estas alturas ya deberíamos saber que tanto `"abc"` como `"def"` son punteros a tipo char y que lo que estamos comparando aquí son **direcciones de memoria** en vez de valores, luego dendiendo de cómo trabaje el compilador, el ejemplo podrá imprimir cualquiera de las dos cadenas. ¿a que mola? Bueno, lo cierto es que no.

**2. Son peligrosas**

Para ilustrar este punto vamos a reutilizar la macro del primer punto.

¿Qué sucedería ante esta secuencia?

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
std::cout << MIN(a++,b++);
```

Si *explotamos* la macro tendremos lo siguiente:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
std::cout << a++ < b++ ? a++ : b++;
```

Y aquí ya empezamos a movernos en terreno resbaladizo pues resulta que nos encontramos ante un comportamiento indeterminado, es decir, que dependerá del compilador darnos un resultado u otro. Para verlo más gráficamente, el código anterior podría acabar convertido en este otro:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
bool resultado = a < b;
a++;
b++;
if( resultado )
  std::cout << a;
else
  std::cout << b;
a++;
b++;
```

O también en este otro;

```
int a = 10;
int b = 5;
bool resultado = a < b;
if( resultado )
  std::cout << a;
else
  std::cout << b;
a++;
a++;
b++;
b++;
```

Y es facil ver que cada código imprime un resultado distinto.

**3. No se pueden depurar**

El código generado por las macros no puede ser depurado y no se pueden poner puntos de parada en dicho código.

Es decir, las macros complican las tareas de depuración del código.

**4. No funcionan con intellisense**

Los IDE modernos tienen intellisense, una utilidad que simplifica muchísimo la vida del programador ya que te da información sobre el código (tipo de una variable, miembros de una clase, etc...) mientras escribes ... y las macros son perfectas para tumbar el sistema.

Si tienes una macro para generar clases o funciones:

```
#define NEW_CLASS(Name,Type) \
class Name \
{ \
  Type var; \
public: \
  Type Get() const \
  { return var; } \
 \
  void Set(Type value) \
  { var = value; } \
};
```

Y creas un par de clases:

```
NEW_CLASS(A,int);
NEW_CLASS(B,float);
```

Podrás utilizarlas en tu programa sin problemas:

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  a.Set(10);
  b.Set(45,6);

  std::cout << a.Get() << ' ' << b.Get();
}
```

Peeeeeero olvídate de que el intellisense funcione. Como mucho sabrá indicarte el código que genera la macro al ser procesada... pero poco más. Te toca aprenderte o revisar la macro para conocer los miembros de `A` y `B` cada vez que quieras usar esas clases.

**Resumen**

Las plantillas, en cambio, no poseen estos problemas así que serían la opción a elegir frente a las macros siempre y cuando sea posible.

Comment: gracias por responder e identificar las desventajas de usar macros